# Go get private repo in gitlab CI

Tags: go, gitlab, gitlab-ci, go-modules

When attempting to download private go dependencies in Gitlab CI, I am given the error:

```
go: gitlab.com/path/to/private/repo@tag: reading gitlab.com/path/to/private/repo/go.mod at revision repo/tag: git ls-remote -q origin in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/b9c14ef4557b9e7a5cee451c4c1a3b7c3f05519199a2d30cb24ae253b6a6fa2b: exit status 128:
    remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
    fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.com/path/to.git/' not found
```

The `.netrc` file is set with a known good value, but it doesn't appear to be working correctly in Gitlab CI. I have replaced my own `.netrc` file with the one I am attempting to use, deleted `~/go/pkg/mod`, and ran `go mod tidy` in my repo which successfully downloaded the private dependencies. Additionally, if I inject the `.netrc` contents into a docker build, and have the docker file retrieve the dependencies, there are no issues.

This is the simplest `.gitlab-ci.yml` file that will replicate:

```
failingJob:
  image: golang:1.17-alpine
  script:
  - apk update && apk add --no-cache git
  - echo "${NETRC}" > /root/.netrc
  - go mod download
  stage: test
  variables:
    GOPRIVATE: gitlab.com/private-org
workingJob:
  image: docker:19.03.12
  services:
  - docker:19.03.12-dind
  script:
    - docker build -t my-docker-image --build-arg SHARE_NETRC="$NETRC" --build-arg GOPRIVATE=gitlab.com/private-org -f docker/Dockerfile .
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.17-alpine AS BUILDER

ARG SHARE_NETRC
ARG GOPRIVATE

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git ca-certificates

COPY . /app/src

ENV GOPRIVATE=${GOPRIVATE}
ENV SHARE_NETRC=${SHARE_NETRC}

RUN echo "${SHARE_NETRC}" > /root/.netrc
WORKDIR /app/src

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags="-w -s" -o /go/bin/app

FROM scratch

COPY --from=BUILDER /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
COPY --from=BUILDER /go/bin/app /

ENTRYPOINT [ "/app" ]
```

As you can see, the image used in the Dockerfile is the same as the image used in Job 1. The values for the `.netrc` file are the same between the jobs, and the location of the file is the same. The only difference I can see between the two jobs is that one is running directly on the runner while the other is in a Docker build context.

Answer (score 0):

What was the content of ${NETRC}? .netrc way works with GitlabCI, and don't forget to use GOPRIVATE as well. Here is the example that works:

```
.git-config-cmd: &git-config-cmd
  - git config --global user.email "your@email.com"
  - git config --global user.name "Your Name"
  - go env -w GOPRIVATE="${CI_SERVER_HOST}/*"
  - echo "machine gitlab.com
  login your_login
  password $YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" >> ~/.netrc
```

This anchor could be injected like:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - *git-config-cmd
    - make test
```

Hope it helps!